# Script or Code to import from AD to Sharepoint Group All users

Tags: active-directory, people-picker, people-search, ldap

I'm looking for a script or code to make Sharepoint know 'bout users from active directory.. I have 3 domains and People Picker sees people but cannot resolve that (suggest only).. I read in many place that to EnsureUser, Sharepoint must know 'bout them so that if I manually add user to sharepoint it works..

How can I do to add entire Active Directory users to SP?

This is my actual code:

```
 public static void Import(string username, string domain,string completeDomain)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, completeDomain);
        Console.WriteLine(ctx.Name + " --> " + ctx.UserName + " --> " + ctx.ConnectedServer);
        Console.ReadKey();

        UserPrincipal findAllUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx); 

        PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(findAllUser);

        try
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                 {
                     using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(GetUrl()))
                     {
                         using (SPWeb web = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
                         {
                             foreach (Principal user in ps.FindAll())
                             {
                                 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                 elevatedSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                 Console.WriteLine(user.Name + "-->" + user.DistinguishedName);
                                 Console.ReadKey();

                                 var loginName = domain + "\\" + user.SamAccountName;
                                 var name = user.DisplayName;
                                 web.AssociatedVisitorGroup.Users.Add(loginName, string.Empty, name, string.Empty);

                             }
                         }

                     }
                 });
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exx.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(exx.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to add all users, just add `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users`

If you want to add every user individually, you have to get users (maybe as Principals) from AD, and [add them to a group in SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercollection.add.aspx).

```
var principal...
var loginName = @"MYDOMAIN\" + principal.SamAccountName;
var name = principal.DisplayName;
web.AssociatedMemberGroup.Users.Add(loginName, "", name, "");
```

Comment: Even adding NT Authority\authenticated users, People Picker cannot solve immediatly names and Ensure User wont work... To make it work i need to "introduce personally" every single user from my AD domains to SP

Comment: Allright, you can iterate over all ad groups, get members and add them to SharePoint. Check out [my blog post about ou, but write about getting members from ad groups as well](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/check-if-a-user-is-in-a-ou/)

Comment: I can get users from AD thanks to you... But in Principal form.. How can i convert this to SPUser?? Or SPPrincipal...

Comment: Then you have to add users to some group in SharePoint.. I'll update my post

Comment: Thank you very much.. Code generates an exception like 80040154..

Comment: Hope you could figure out the problems. Share you findings if you can.